# Excel VBA - Autofiltered row count is always returning 1

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofilter

I'm currently using autofilter to filter on two columns.  If the result of the autofilter is blank for only visible cells, it will add a new row.  If any rows other than the header are found, it will instead show a MsgBox.  The problem is that the row count is always returning 1.  I've tried redefining "rng" a few ways to no avail.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Scored Items")

Worksheets("Scored Items").Activate

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

With ws

    .Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=AssetBox.Text
    .Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=PartBox.Text

    Set rng = .Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If (rng.Rows.Count = 1) Then
        'Add new row based on VBA form
    Else
        MsgBox "Item has already been scored"
    End If
End With

ws.Cells.AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking the Rows.Count, check Cells.Count for visible rows.
Try it like this...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Scored Items")
lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Worksheets("Scored Items").Activate

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

With ws
    .Range("A1:D" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=AssetBox.Text
    .Range("A1:D" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=PartBox.Text
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If rng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        'Add new row based on VBA form
    Else
        MsgBox "Item has already been scored"
    End If
End With
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: This solution also works well and is a bit cleaner.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If the range object is non-contiguous, than `.Rows.Count` will only return the number of rows in the first `Area` of the range, which in this case will be the "header" row.  (NB: If your filter was such that the *first* row of data was visible, but the second was not, you'd get `2` as the result).

When working with filtered ranges, you need to iterate the `Areas` in the range.

```
    Dim aRange as Range
    For Each aRange in rng.Areas
        If (aRange.Rows.Count = 1) Then
            'Add new row based on VBA form
        Else
            MsgBox "Item has already been scored"
        End If
    Next
```

In this case, you probably want to flag some error if `Areas.Count > 2` and also if any of the `aRange.Rows.Count <> 1` etc.

If you're using `AutoFilter` merely to check for the existence of a value in this range (i.e., to prevent duplicate entries in a table?), that's a rather clunky way to do it and you would probably be better served using the `COUNTIF` function.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"),AssetBox.Text) = 1 And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("D:D"), PartBox.Text) = 1 Then
    'Add new row based on VBA Form
Else
    MsgBox "Item has already been scored"
End If
```

Follow-up from your comment, since this is a UI, I would use *both*. Obviously, you want the AutoFilter to display the data to the user, so keep that. But rather than trying to hack around the various `Areas` of the filtered data, just use the `COUNTIF` function to check

```
'Filter data to display to the user
Dim dataRange As Range
Set dataRange = ws.Range("A:D")
With dataRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=AssetBox.Text
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=PartBox.Text

    'Check if part already been scored
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountIf(.Columns(1), AssetBox.Text) = 1 And _
        .CountIf(.Columns(4), PartBox.Text) = 1 Then
        'Add new row based on VBA Form
    Else
        MsgBox "Item has already been scored"
    End If
End With
'unfilter the data
ws.Cells.AutoFilter
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Part of the reason I chose to do this using autofilter is to show the individual using the tool which record already exists as a match.  I will likely add the ability to overwrite with the new entry if desired.

Comment: @Sedako sure thing, that makes sense! If the answer has solved your problem, do consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)